# What is the most direct way of filtering data (a list of jobs) from one sheet to another, based on a dropdown above where the filtered data should be?

Tags: google-sheets, filtering

I have a Google Sheets workbook with 2 sheets.  The first sheet will pull information from the second so that a label showing a list of required jobs can be easily printed. There is a dropdown that should allow you to show only the jobs required for one specific client.  Attempting to do this with a formula rather than any script.

The second sheet has a list of standard jobs available in column B.  Columns C to J have checkboxes that would be checked if the specific client (shown in the row above checkboxes) wants the specific job to be performed.

What is the best way to filter the data from the second sheet onto the first sheet?

Sample sheet below.  Included a sample sheet to show how I had hoped to get the data to display.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ne75TQhiiPtvsmwWQTsf2NsJu0kiaM4niCWhbB7g7v4/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried several variations of IF and Filter functions, but cannot get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=filter('Client Service Needs'!B3:B14,filter('Client Service Needs'!C3:J14,'Client Service Needs'!C2:J2=B3))
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I needed.  Thank you for the assist.  I was close, but kept overthinking it and trying to complicate the problem by adding an IF statement.  It's been a long week and I'm totally drained.  Thanks again!!!